# How to insert a single doc into two different collection java script and mongojs

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongojs

Am trying to insert data into two different table using javascript and mongojs but i cant seem to succeed
using the npm mongojs documentation i got this to work for a single collection insert, on searching this platform i only found solution for other languages
any help will be appreciated

```
// var Delivered = require('../model/booking/booking').Delivered,
var  Completed = require('../model/booking/booking').Completed,
express = require('express')
    app = express(),
    mongojs = require('mongojs'),
    db = mongojs('mongodb:coolection',["completeds", "delivereds","deliveredhistory"]);

function route(app){
    app.post('/shipper/completed',function(req, res){

    var item_id = req.body.item_id
        var id = mongojs.ObjectId(item_id);

        db.delivereds.findAndModify({
            "query":{ "_id": id },
            "remove": false
            },

            function(err,data) {

                    if (data) {

                        db.completeds.insert(data,function(err,data){
                            if(err){
                                res.json({
                                    status:400,
                                    message:"Failed to mark as complete",
                                    err:err
                                })
                            }
                            else{
                                res.json({
                                    status:200,
                                    message:"Job successfully completed",
                                    data:data

                                });
                            }
                        });
                    } 
                    else {
                    console.log("fake number")
                    res.json({
                        status: 403,
                        message:'This load is not available for accepting'
             })
          }

     })
})
}
module.exports.route = route;
```

What am trying to do is to still insert to another collection say 'deliveredhistory'
please help out

i tried something like this but didnt work

```
(db.completeds&&db.deliveredhistory)insert(data,function(err,data){
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually found a way out

i created a new model for deliveredhistory the initiated the insert method after  `if(err){....}`
 was completed without an error then i implement another insert method before the `res.json({...})` which is under the else condition

like this

```
if (data) {

                    db.completeds.insert(data,function(err,data){
                        if(err){
                            res.json({
                                status:400,
                                message:"Failed to mark as complete",
                                err:err
                            })
                        }
                        else{
                           db.deliveredhistory.insert(data) //this is where the insert for the second collection took place
                           res.json({
                                status:200,
                                message:"Job successfully completed",
                                data:data
```

I hope this is helpful to someone else somewhere